# Symfony Argument n passed to *** must be an instance of Swift_Mailer, null giveno

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-4.2

I'm struggling with Symfony 3.4 and autowiring.

He here an exemple of the error message :
`Argument 2 passed to App\Controller\MainController::contact() must be an instance of Swift_Mailer, null given`

It's the same message with every **Service** I pass as argument.

There is probably something missing in the configuration but I can't figure out what...

Any clue ?

```
// config/services.yaml
parameters:
    google_recaptcha_site_key: '%env(GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY)%'

services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

  App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller'
    public: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

```
// src/Controller/MainController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Exception;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

class MainController extends AbstractController
{
 public function contact(
        Request $request,
        \Swift_Mailer $mailer,
        Validation $validation,
    ) { ... }
}
```

Comment: It would be good to add code of your controller's constructor along with `use` statements

Comment: Also it is helpful to use Symfony's built-in container debugger: `php -f bin/console debug:container debug:container <service name>`, maybe it will give you a hint

Comment: Post the configuration of your service and your controller

Comment: How do you include `Swift_Mailer` into project? Directly, as `swiftmailer/swiftmailer` or as Symfony bundle `symfony/swiftmailer-bundle`?

Comment: via symfony/swiftmailer-bundle

Comment: It looks quite strange then, did you tried to look at `debug:container` command output for `\Swift_Mailer` or `mailer`?

Comment: debug:container |grep mailer
```Swift_Mailer alias for "swiftmailer.mailer.default"
...
```

Comment: I have no idea to be true, but I would recommend: 1. try to pass mailer to constructor to see if there will be any difference; 2. look inside container itself to see how controller is being instantiated, it is located into `getMainControllerService.php`. Hope it will give some hint to fix the issue

Comment: Thanks @Flying for your help, I ended creating a new app from scratch and comparing behaviour while adding bundle one by one. CF my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to solve my problem.

I had **Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle** enabled, and it seems that we can't have **sensio/framework-extra-bundle** and **symfony/flex** (or maybe with additionnal configuration).